# Can't run sudo apt get update on Update PHP on Google compute engine

Tags: linux, debian, php, sudo, google-compute-engine

I want to update my PHP version on my VM and for that, I have to run sudo apt-get update on my VM in compute engine (google cloud platform) But I keep getting an error saying public key not available

Here is my environment:

`Linux wordpress-1-vm 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Here are the errors I get:

`Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute InRelease Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute Release 404  Not Found Reading package lists... Done E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Can someone help ? please

Comment: Hirsuite is pre-release. You should use a release or an LTS version https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't understand. I'm not used to Linux. Do you have a link to refer me to, please ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the debia DPA instead of the Ubutnu PPA then import the gpg key (to solve the apt-secure error).

Remove the Sury PPA from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` .

```
sudo apt -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl
sudo curl -sSL -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
sudo apt update
```

[Ondřej Surý](https://deb.sury.org/)

[Installation guide: ReadMe script](https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt)